# Pressing the tilde key (~) waits for a second key stroke, how do I disable this? (2020 version)

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Answers to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/414405/pressing-the-tilde-key-waits-for-a-second-key-stroke-how-do-i-disable-this) are outdated, as the tool from Microsoft is no longer avaiable.
Are there any other solutions?

**EDIT:**
I'm using Windows 10, and my keyboard layout is polish.

**EDIT 2:**
The links in the updated answer appear to work (thanks @user1686!), I have accepted the lazy solution of just pressing space.
Not exactly ideal, but easy enough that I will probably use that instead of tinkering with custom keyboard layouts on every system I use.

**Microsoft, shame on you for not allowing users to customize their layouts by default!**

Comment: Does the same happen for other keys, like ' or " ? if so, you need to not use an International English keyboard layout, use your native Language instead, US, or UK etc

Comment: What your exact keyboard layout?

Comment: I have updated the linked thread with Archive.org links, which still have both versions of MSKLC available. Are the described methods outdated as well, or do they work on your system?

Comment: What Operating System???

Answer (score 2):

This will happen if you use a keyboard layout that supports this, such as US International.

Add a second keyboard layout that is United States, and switch to it, and the problem will be gone.

Comment: I'm using a language specific layout though... I guess it is safe to assume that not every layout that utilizes tilde to modify the following input has a good twin, that doesn't?

Comment: You use United States as your global layout, and switch to your language specific layout when you need all its functions. Its like this for 20 years now, or so. That's why you can switch languages by pressing alt-shift or ctrl-shift

Comment: Pressing windows-space kinda beat the purpose. I want less keystrokes, not more.

Comment: You're not getting me. You switch the layout, then until you switch back, ~ is all you need to do. I find that I only seldomly actually need the language specific layout, so its most of the time set to US, and goes to language specific when I really need it.

Comment: Well, I do need my layout pretty much all the time and keeping track of which one I'm using would be **much** more of a hassle than typing <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> every now and then as @Hannu suggested.

Comment: Yeah, in that case there's no solution, given that Hannu's suggestion is a workaround, not an answer. But its a good workaround nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to get the actual character out of these "compose"-type keys might be:

e.g. <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> to get `~`

It doesn't work with all of them though.

---

Added 2020-09-02:

*Note that these key are intended to allow e.g. entry of characters like ñ, Ñ, ü, Ü, åÅ, äÄ, öÖ and many others. The actual umlauts++ might not be available as singled out characters.*