# Win10 change Alt Gr behaviour

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout, language

I've got a United Kingdom keyboard layout. I want to use English as preferred language, but at the same time be able to type Polish special characters using AltGr / right alt. I think that Ubuntu offers Polish lang at UK layout, but I don't see that in Win10. Important thing is I don't want to switch language using Alt+Shift combination - I want to be able to change keyboard used while right alt is pressed down, but keep English as default always. Is there a way to do it?

Bonus points for an answer that doesn't even allow me to change lang using alt+shift, but works properly when right alt is held down

Comment: just [create your own keyboard layout using MSKLC](https://superuser.com/a/414415/241386)

Comment: What do you define as "Polish special characters"? I don't speak Polish [as you may have guessed] but Alt/Gr on a UK keyboard can be swapped between these two alternatives - UK Eng default https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy8BZ.png English International https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOb6H.png if that's any use to you.